# Como eu coloco e retiro um href dinamicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho esse href: `<a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumentoDown")%></a>`

O que eu quero é que eu crio um link apenas quando eu retorno da procedure o `DsPathDocumento` e `NmTipoDocumentoDown`. Isso está no Asp.Net.

Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script>$('#idLocal').append('<a href = \'url\'></a>');</script>", false);
```

Ou isso:

```
<asp:Button id="myid" runat="server" OnClientClick="$('#idLocal').append('<a href = \'url\'></a>')"/>
```

O código em js está usando jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Tem várias maneiras.
Uma delas, sem alterar muito o código, é adicionar no `a` um `runat="server"` e um `id='nome'`.

```
 <a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" runat="server" class="linkUpload"><%#Eval("NmTipoDocumentoDown")%></a>
```

Daí, no seu `.cs` vai ter como referenciar o seu `nome` como qualquer outro controle.

Outra forma é você colocar um objeto do tipo `HyperLink` e setar o seu `Visible="false"`. Você pode setar o seu `NavigateUrl` (link) do seu `.cs`. Somente exiba o link quando você precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que parece DsPathDocumento é uma string, logo pode usar algo do tipo :

Não gosto muito de escrever em ASP.NET usando inline code, mas já que você já está usando, aí vai uma alternativa :

```
<% if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento ").ToString())) { %>
    <a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumentoDown")%></a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Também não gosto, mas já está assim. Prefiro no code behind.